# How to trigger update panel using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Currently I am using below script to trigger update panel:

```
   var updatePanelID = 'updatePnl';
   __doPostBack(updatePanelID, 'UPDATE');
```

It's working fine on Chrome, firefox, but when it comes to IE, the below error flows:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode
```

Below is my Html Header:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Try putting the <meta> tag right after they <doctype>. That line should alywas come before the page content. I've always used it right after my doctype and seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a work around for this:

I made a refresh button at the bottom of the page, and associate the button to the update panel, and whenever I need to trigger the update panel, I use

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>').click();
```